# New variable by date range in R

Tags: r, algorithm

I am trying to create a new variable that is based on customer_id and dates.  The table is a log of all customer contact, so there will be duplicate customer IDs.  What I want to do it create a new variable that has a sequential count by using dates of contact within x days for each customer.  All first contact from a customer will be = 1 and if there is a gap greater than x days since last contact, then that contact will be 2 and so on and so forth.  I am trying to create the "Journey" variable.

Thanks for any guidance.

[image]

here is the code:

```
structure(list(Customer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    Start_dt = c("2018-04-30 13:47:13", "2018-05-03 09:22:25", 
    "2018-04-22 10:45:33", "2018-04-20 09:55:51", "2018-04-21 14:20:33", 
    "2018-05-01 15:27:43", "2018-03-28 11:25:45", "2018-04-28 10:30:35", 
    "2018-05-17 11:08:51", "2018-06-02 10:38:38"), End_dt = c("2018-04-30 14:22:15", 
    "2018-05-03 10:05:32", "2018-04-22 11:00:35", "2018-04-20 09:57:45", 
    "2018-04-21 14:27:14", "2018-05-01 16:03:25", "2018-03-28 11:35:54", 
    "2018-04-28 11:02:17", "2018-05-17 12:32:18", "2018-06-02 11:08:29"
    ), Journey = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: So what did you actually try yourself? Take a look here [How to ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your data. You should review how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to provide (1) sample data in a copy&paste-able format (e.g. use `dput`), (2) your code attempt, and (3) your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the algorithm below which is converting `character` vector into `Date` object, then it splits `data.frame` by factor column. Inside `lapply` function the algorithm is checking the conditions for Journey identification using `zlag` function. In the end it is using `do.call` function to concatenate data frames.

```
df <- structure(list(Customer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    Start_dt = structure(c(17651, 17654, 17643, 17641, 17642, 
    17652, 17618, 17649, 17668, 17684), class = "Date"), End_dt = structure(c(17651, 
    17654, 17643, 17641, 17642, 17652, 17618, 17649, 17668, 17684
    ), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
library(lubridate, TSA)
df$Start_dt <- as_date(df$Start_dt)
df$End_dt <- as_date(df$End_dt)

x <- 10 # 10 days

y <- lapply(
  X = split(df, df$Customer), 
  FUN = function(dfx) {
    dfx$lagged <- as_date(zlag(dfx$Start_dt))
    dfx$dt <- dfx$Start_dt - dfx$lagged
    dfx$dt <- ifelse(dfx$dt < x, 0, 1)
    dfx$dt[1] <- 1
    dfx$Journey <- cumsum(dfx$dt)
    dfx[, -c(5:6)]
})
z <- do.call(rbind, y)
rownames(z) <- NULL
z
```

Output:

```
   Customer   Start_dt     End_dt Journey
1         A 2018-04-30 2018-04-30       1
2         A 2018-05-03 2018-05-03       1
3         B 2018-04-22 2018-04-22       1
4         C 2018-04-20 2018-04-20       1
5         C 2018-04-21 2018-04-21       1
6         C 2018-05-01 2018-05-01       2
7         D 2018-03-28 2018-03-28       1
8         D 2018-04-28 2018-04-28       2
9         D 2018-05-17 2018-05-17       3
10        D 2018-06-02 2018-06-02       4
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is a more streamlined `data.table` version of [Artem's `cumsum()` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52410272/3817004):

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
x <- 9
setDT(df)[, journey := 1 + cumsum(shift(End_dt, fill = End_dt[1]) + days(x) < Start_dt), 
          by = Customer]

df
```

> ```
>     Customer            Start_dt              End_dt journey
>  1:        A 2018-04-30 13:47:13 2018-04-30 14:22:15       1
>  2:        A 2018-05-03 09:22:25 2018-05-03 10:05:32       1
>  3:        B 2018-04-22 10:45:33 2018-04-22 11:00:35       1
>  4:        C 2018-04-20 09:55:51 2018-04-20 09:57:45       1
>  5:        C 2018-04-21 14:20:33 2018-04-21 14:27:14       1
>  6:        C 2018-05-01 15:27:43 2018-05-01 16:03:25       2
>  7:        D 2018-03-28 11:25:45 2018-03-28 11:35:54       1
>  8:        D 2018-04-28 10:30:35 2018-04-28 11:02:17       2
>  9:        D 2018-05-17 11:08:51 2018-05-17 12:32:18       3
> 10:        D 2018-06-02 10:38:38 2018-06-02 11:08:29       4
> ```

#### Data

Initially, the OP has only posted a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OVuP.png) of his data. I have tried to convert the image with help of an [online OCR converter](https://www.free-ocr.com/) which worked pretty well for both datetime columns:

```
library(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(
  Customer = rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(2, 1, 3, 4)),
  readr::read_csv("Start_dt
2018—04—30 13:47:13
2018—05-03 09:22:25
2018—04—22 10:45:33
2018—04—20 09:55:51
2018—04—21 14:20:33
2018—05—01 15:27:43
2018—03—28 11:25:45
2018—04-28 10:30:35
2018—05—17 11:08:51
2018—06-02 10:38:38
") %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_all(lubridate::ymd_hms),
  readr::read_csv("End_dt
2018—04—30 14:22:15
2018—05—03 10:05:32
2018—04—22 11:00:35
2018—04-20 09:57:45
2018—04—21 14:27:14
2018—05—01 16:03:25
2018—03—28 11:35:54
2018—04—28 11:02:17
2018—05—17 12:32:18
2018—06—02 11:08:29
") %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_all(lubridate::ymd_hms)
)
```

Comment: it's really cool what you've done with `data.table`. I'll certainly have a look.